# populate date field in new form based on another date field in the same form

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-form

[image]

I want to load End Date field as start date field +2 years when user enter start date. this is a new form of my list.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can be handle using `Content Editor WebPart` or `Script Editor WebPart`.

You can edit the `NewForm.aspx` and add the `CEWP/SEWP` and handle the change event for the `StartDate` control. And based on this you can manage your `EndDate` control.

Similar post is shown [Auto-Populate the Field Values Based on Text Change in SharePoint Online List Forms](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/auto-populate-the-field-values-based-on-text-change-in-share/).

Comment: i want to populate based on one field in the same form/list.

Comment: In that case can't you use Calculated Field shown by @Milad?

Comment: in calculated field list will be updated only, but i want to populate on the form at the time of filling

Comment: What you want is Auto populate the EndDate based on StartDate as soon as you select StartDate right?

Comment: yes yes rightly said.

Answer (score 0):

try  this

and use a Calculated Field

```
=DATE(YEAR([Start Date])+2,MONTH([Start Date]),DAY([Start Date]))
```